# Date Conversion problem

Tags: ssis

I was about to import data from a table in MySQL to SQL SErver 2008 through SSIS. But I cant transfer due to Dates in the table. There are some data of datetime data type, like '0001-01-10' which doesnt support in SQL Server where years in date ranges from 1753 to 9999. So how do i solve this in MySQL queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those dates are valid data, then there's no easy way to deal with that in SqlServer.  Basically, a custom date handler is needed.  A good-enough approximation might be achieved by separating the year into a single integer field and putting the month and day into a date field with a constant year.  Every comparison would then be compound.

More likely—for most business applications—such dates are useless and should be cleaned up, or replaced by NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **none** of the SSIS data types are truly equivalent to the SQL Server *datetime* or *smalldatetime* types, with their restricted range of allowable dates.

A lot of online documentation suggests the DT_DBTIMESTAMP is equivalent to SQL *datetime*.  This is only true up to a point.  Dates outside the allowed *datetime* range will happily cast to DT_DBTIMESTAMP (or any SSIS date type) - but will then cause an error if you try to write them out to an SQL *datetime* column.

Confusingly, SSIS represents external SQL *datetime* columns as DT_DBTIMESTAMP, suggesting that *datetime* and DT_DBTIMESTAMP are equivalent, when they're not.

This means that you can't anticipate out-of-range date problems in SSIS by casting.  If you're eventually going to write to *datetime* or *smalldatetime* columns, you have to do an explicit check that the date is not out of range (<1/1/1753, or 1/1/1900 for smalldatetime).